# САмостоятельное нажатие клавиши в игре

Tags: макросы

Есть игра в которой каждые 5 - 10 секунд респауниться какой то предмет... Мне его нужно забирать, для этого нужно нажать клавишу допустим  "F" но это нужно делать очень и очень долго что бы собрать много и продать... Вот у меня такой вопрос, а можно запрограммировать клавишу F на самостоятельное нажатие через каждые 5 секунд... Что бы можно было запустить игру и пойти на работу или просто куда угодно, аоставить только игру включённой и что бы она сама все собирала?

Comment: и да, в онлайн-играх за такое запросто банят.

Answer (score 3):

Как раз для таких вещей есть [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вам нужен автокликер или же нечто подобное. Посмотрите "Автокликер для клавиатуры" в гугле и пользуйтесь на здоровье) Удачи на "полях сражений" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Напрмиер, встроенный в Windows язык VBS:

```
Do
sendkeys('f')
sleep(5000)
Loop
```

1. Сохраните под названием **fkey.vbs**
2. Создайте ярлык на этот файл и укажите в свойствах этого ярлыка
   быстрый
3. запуск(например, ctrl+alt+c)
4. Запускаете вашу игру и нажимаете указанную ранее комбинацию клавиш
5. Profit.